# How to draw wifi channel graph with Python programming

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Hi Im a beginner with python graph

I have some wifi data(Dataframe) like this

| SSID | RSSI | Channel | r_range | l_range | Bandwidth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ASUS_Kurt | -76 | 2 | 0.0 | 4.0 | 20MHz |
| Javen-2.4G | -91 | 3 | 1.0 | 9.0 | 40MHz |
| LIN | -62 | 6 | 4.0 | 8.0 | 20MHz |
| wcs2.4G | -64 | 11 | 9.0 | 13.0 | 20MHz |
| LIN-EXT | -74 | 11 | 5.0 | 13.0 | 40MHz |

How to draw a Wifi-Channel graph like this using matplotlib or seaborn

[image]

And I try like this code:

```
plt.cla()
a = [['test', -87, 6, 4, 8]]
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['ssid', 'rssi', 'channel', 'r', 'l'])
x = np.linspace(df['r'], df['l'], 50)
y = int(df['rssi']) * np.sin((x - int(df['channel']) + 2) / 4 * np.pi)
plt.fill(x, y, color='r', alpha=0.3)
plt.show()
```

print graph like this

[image]

not my want.

`y.value` should be `-99` to `0` and `frequency height` should be like `-99` to `-87`, only `13` height in channel `6`

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code?

Comment: i try like this 
x = np.linspace(df['r'], df['l'], 50)
y = int(df['rssi']) * np.sin((x - int(df['channel']) + 2) / 4 * np.pi)
f, ax = plt.subplots(1)
plt.fill(x, y, color='r', alpha=0.3)

Comment: but plot not my want y.values should be -99 to 0, and column height should be like if rssi='-87' channel:6, only -13dbm height, sry I'm first to try python graph

Comment: did you try `y = -99 - y` to flip data?

Comment: you may need also `int(-99-row['rssi'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I use `-99` (or `-100`)

```
 y = (-99 - row['rssi']) * ...
```

and

```
 y = -99 - y
```

then I flip values and I get expected plot

[image]

---

Minimale working code.

BTW: For some ranges (`l - r > 4`) it needs different calcualtions.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    ('ASUS_Kurt',  -76,  2, 0.0,  4.0),
#    ('Javen-2.4G', -91,  3, 1.0,  9.0),   # need different calculations
    ('LIN',        -62,  6, 4.0,  8.0),
    ('wcs2.4G',    -64, 11, 9.0, 13.0),
#    ('LIN-EXT',    -74, 11, 5.0, 13.0),   # need different calculations
    ('test1',      -87,  6, 4.0,  8.0),
    ('test2',      -80, 11, 9.0, 13.0),
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ssid', 'rssi', 'channel', 'r', 'l'])

plt.cla()

all_colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'y']

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    x = np.linspace(row['r'], row['l'], 50)
    y = (-99-row['rssi']) * np.sin((x - row['channel'] + 2) / 4 * np.pi)
    y = -99-y
    color = all_colors[ index % len(all_colors) ]
    plt.fill(x, y, color=color, alpha=0.3)
    
plt.show()
```

---

**EDIT:**

[image]

`Javen-2.4G` and `LIN-EXT` may need different calculations because `channel` is not in the middle between `r` and `l`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    ('ASUS_Kurt',  -76,  2, 0.0,  4.0),
    ('Javen-2.4G', -91,  3, 1.0,  9.0),   # need different calculations
    ('LIN',        -62,  6, 4.0,  8.0),
    ('wcs2.4G',    -64, 11, 9.0, 13.0),
    ('LIN-EXT',    -74, 11, 5.0, 13.0),   # need different calculations
    ('test1',      -87,  6, 4.0,  8.0),
    ('test2',      -80, 11, 9.0, 13.0),
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ssid', 'rssi', 'channel', 'r', 'l'])

all_colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'y']

plt.cla()

plt.xlabel('Wifi Channel')
plt.ylabel('Signal Strength [dBm]')

plt.grid(axis='y', linestyle='--')
plt.grid(axis='x', linestyle=':', color='r', alpha=0.3)

y_major_ticks = np.arange(0, -100, -10)
plt.gca().set_yticks(y_major_ticks)

x_major_ticks = np.arange(0, 15, 1)
plt.gca().set_xticks(x_major_ticks)

plt.ylim(-100, 0)
plt.xlim(-2, 16)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    diff = (row['l'] - row['r'])
    x = np.linspace(row['r'], row['l'], 50)
    y = (-99-row['rssi']) * np.sin((x - row['r']) / diff * np.pi)
    y = -99-y
    
    color = all_colors[ index % len(all_colors) ]
    
    plt.fill(x, y, color=color, alpha=0.3)
    plt.plot(x, y, color=color)    
    plt.text(row['channel'], row['rssi']+1, row['ssid'], horizontalalignment='center')
    
plt.show()
```